# Reading data from a text file

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a text file as a database for some data I collect from a user, this is a constructor I'm using

```
public DatabaseOperations(String name,double newWeight) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException{
    f= new File (removeSpaces(name)+".txt");
    if (!f.exists()){
        System.out.println("This user dosen't exist");
        return;
    }
    try {
        out= new PrintWriter (f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error, You don't say");
    }
    // This section is used to initialize a new object from Customer with values in the excising file
    cust = new Customer();
    in=new Scanner(f);
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setName(in.next());
    in.next();
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setStartingDate(in.next());
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setAge(Integer.parseInt(in.next()));
    in.next();
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setStartingWeight(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
    in.next();
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setBMI(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
    in.next();
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setTargetWeight(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
    in.next();
    in.next();
    in.next();
    cust.setTargetDate(in.next());
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // check this for errors !!!
    cust.setWeight(newWeight);
    out.println(form.format(cust.getCurrentDate())+"\t"+df.format(cust.getWeight())+"\t\t"+cust.getBMI()+"\t\t"+cust.percentDone()+"\t"+cust.timePassed());
    out.close();
}
```

these many in.next() are used to skip some data I don't need, the structure of the file I'm using is like that

```
Name :kkkk  Started at :06/12/2012
Age :19 Starting Weight :85.0
Height :1.86        Starting BMI :24.57
Target Weight :75.5 Target Date :15/12/2012
```

the problem is that the compiler throws a NoSuchElementException and points me to the first (in.next())
another problem is that as soon as I invoke this constructor the file becomes empty !!!

Comment: I would suggest you research some existing flat-file database providers (e.g. http://db.apache.org/derby/). Writing your own is a painful exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the `java.util.Properties` class if you want to use a text-file instead of a database. No need for using `next()`, you can solve this with key/value pairs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
  prop.load(new FileInputStream(removeSpaces(name)+".txt"));
  cust.setAge(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("age")));
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The properties text-file looks like this

```
age=19
name=kkkk
started_at=06/12/2012
starting_weight=85.0
```

Comment: what should I enter instead of "name.properties" and "key" ?? sorry I didn't get the idea of properties and keys yet

Comment: @user1712638 name.properties is your file where you store the data (removeSpaces(name)+".txt"). And instead of "age:19" you store the data as "age=19" ('age' is your key, '19' is your value). Put each key/value pair in a new line.

Comment: Now I'm trying   cust.setName(prop.getProperty("Name"));
and it throws a null point exception !!

Comment: @user1712638 Your property is null then, check your file! Is the format correct? Maybe space somewhere? I edited to give you a better idea.

Comment: This is strcture of the file is like this Name=Ahmed
Started at=07/12/2012
Age=19
Starting Weight=85.0
Height=1.86
Starting BMI=24.57
Target Weight=75.5
Target Date=15/12/2012
The problem is that I'm sure that the text file contains this data .. but as soon as I invoke this constructor .. it becomes empty !!!

Comment: @user1712638 Well this is how it's done, it's quite simple and much cleaner. You have to debug your application and see what the problem is, I can't help you there now. Does your file exist, is the path right, can it be read, is the format correct etc, those are the points you have to check.

Comment: Don't use spaces in your key! Look at my example. Also, just use the FileInputStream, nothing else. That should work.

Comment: I removed the spaces but my problem now is to find out what happens to the file !!

Comment: Like I said, I gave you all you need and can't help you anymore, it's beyond your question. You seem to have a problem reading the file. You have to track down exceptions by debugging. Set breakpoints to find out what happens at certain lines of code. Do it step by step. You have to learn how to do that. It takes time, but it's tremendously important when programming, or you will never be able to solve problems on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
String name,date,age,wight,height,....;
LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("File1")));
lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(file.hasNextLine()) {
String str = file.nextLine();
String[] str1 = str.split(" ");
list.add(str1[1]);
list.add(str1[str1.length() - 1]);
}
cust.setAge(list.get(0));
.....
.....
```

Comment: lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
what does that line do ??

Comment: @user1712638 If you want to pursue your approach go ahead, that's your decision. I would not recommend it. If one line changes, or if the order of the lines changes, your code will break. I guess you are a beginner, better to learn clean coding from the beginning.

Comment: I'm a beginner, that's why I asking :) .. and I'm going to use the properties class because it fits best to my program .. I'm just asking him to learn another approach which might help me in an another problem